# How to Generalize a windows VM in azure using ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-virtual-machine

As a part of automating my infra deployment, I need to automate VM creation, installation of software in that vm  and capture a image out of it using Ansible.

Below is the snippet i have for generalizing the vm :

```
- name: Deallocate the vm
  azure_rm_virtualmachine:
    resource_group: "{{rg_name}}"
    name: "{{vm_name}}"
    allocated : yes
- name:
  azure_rm_image:
     resource_group: "{{rg_name}}"
     name: "{{ vm_name}}-image"
     source : "{{vm_name}}"
```

On creating a vm from the image obtained using above step, i get an error in the azure portal stating "The vm has not been generalized properly" .

Any thoughts where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

well, you have to generalize your vm before capturing it. if we are talking about windows, you need to sysprep it first. Azure won't do that for you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource#generalize-the-windows-vm-using-sysprep

Comment: I have generalized windows using below power shell script :Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\Sysprep.exe -ArgumentList '/generalize /oobe /shutdown /quiet' . Still on deployment i get an error